# Map API links from array as React Class Component's state/props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a class component that displays API from data. Link is inserted from an array as a props and it all works fine:

```
let urls = [
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774944', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774945', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774946',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/123581', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782691', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782485',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782486', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782487', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782488',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/738471'];

class Item extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    output: {},
    url: ulrs[0]
}
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.state.url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
  }
render() {
    console.log(this.state.output);
    const { general = {name:"", description:""} } = this.state.output;
    const { brand = {name : ""} } = this.state.output;
    const { id } = this.state.output;
    const {images = {primary:{large:""}}} = this.state.output;
  return (
    [<ItemPanel>
    <ItemBox>
    <BoxTitle>{general.name}</BoxTitle>
    <BoxId>Item ID: {id}</BoxId>
    <Details onClick={show_details}>Show more...</Details>
        <Inline>
        <Quantity type="number" defaultValue="1"></Quantity>
        <Icon>add_shopping_cart</Icon>
        </Inline>
        <AddItem>
        <Sfont>Add to cart</Sfont>
    </AddItem>
    </ItemBox>
        <BoxImg src={images.primary.large} alt='img error'></BoxImg>
</ItemPanel>, 
<DetailsView id="details_view">
<ItemDetails id='details_id'>
<Close onClick={show_details}>x</Close>
  <BoxTitle>{general.name}</BoxTitle>
  <BigImg src={images.primary.large} alt='img error'></BigImg>
  <BoxId>Item ID: {id}</BoxId>
  <Brand>Made by: {brand.name}</Brand>
  {Parser(general.description)}
  <Inline>
        <Quantity type="number" defaultValue="1"></Quantity>
        <Icon>add_shopping_cart</Icon>
        </Inline>
        <AddItem>
        <Sfont>Add to cart</Sfont>
    </AddItem>

   </ItemDetails>
   </DetailsView>
    ]);}}
```

What I wish to do, is a function of some sort that creates multiple components based on one template, but with different data from API. I was trying something like this:

```
let Show_items = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    let urls = [
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774944', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774945', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/774946',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/123581', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782691', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782485',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782486', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782487', 
    'http://localhost:3005/products/782488',
    'http://localhost:3005/products/738471'];
    let ItemsReady = urls.map(function(link, index){
                    return {Item(link)};
                })

    return  ItemsReady;
}});
```

and I was aiming to export ItemsReady to index.js and render it to DOM to display multiple components in my app. Unfortunetly I wasn't able to figure it out yet, so help is very appreciated here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take this urls array from parent component as a prop, and map on the array in parent component.
Example: let suppose you have a parent component App in which you've this array of urls,
now you've to map on it and call your child component i.e: Item on each iteration.

```
//in your parent component
urls.map((url,index)=>{
return(
  <Item key={index} url={url}/>
)
})
// now child component i.e: Item
//all code will be same just take the url from props instead of state while fetching
componentDidMount() {
fetch(this.props.url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ output: data }));
}
```